# Netskope DNS within Linux Container not resolving

Tags: networking

I am using Netskope on Debian host OS,

App in docker container is unable to resolve private DNS eg: `corp.cloud`,
while on host OS, private DNS is resolved OK.

Using Netskope on Windows host OS, App in docker container resolved OK.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Hi @Lydon Ch, what network settings did you (attempt to) configure? What commands/tools are you using for testing connectivity? What about publicly available DNS?

Comment: posted the workaround in answer section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround:

use "host" network

docker run --name swiss-army-knife4 --net="host" -itd leodotcloud/swiss-army-knife